# Is this the same character?

Tags: character, x-men-cinematic-universe, x-men-days-of-future-past

In [X-Men: Days of Future Past](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Men%3a_Days_of_Future_Past), Toad appears with a different appearance compared to his depiction in the 1st [X-Men](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Men_%28film%29) movie, played by a different actor. Even their ages are contradictory. Is this Toad the same version or are there two Toads in the film series?

Comment: Do you mean he's different from the X-Men 1 version or that there are two different versions in DoFP alone?

Comment: @NapoleonWilson i mean do they have two version of toad(1st x-men 1) and second(dofp verison) or both toad are same.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Toad from X-Men: Days of Future Past ([Evan Jonigkeit)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ray_Park) is supposed to be a younger, darker version of the Toad from X-Men ([Ray Park)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ray_Park).

From [an interview with Evan](http://screenrant.com/x-men-days-of-future-past-toad/):

> Jonigkeit, a fan of the books, will very likely have minimal screen
>   time and dialogue [in X-Men Days of Future Past] – sadly like most of the characters we know about –
>   but he does confirm that his Toad does setup the Ray Park version from
>   the original X-Men, but is quite a bit different.
>
> ”I read a lot of the comic books. I found out the storyline of my
>   character, who is Toad. X-Men fans will know that Ray Park played him
>   in the first movie, so it’s a generation story of how he came to be.
>   It’s really cool.”
>
> “The aesthetics of the character are much different, and I’m not
>   really allowed to say a whole lot more than that,” he said. “It’s
>   darker. I would say it’s a darker tone.”

[Apparently](http://marvel-movies.wikia.com/wiki/Mortimer_Toynbee#Trivia) the original actor (Ray Park) was supposed to be in X-Men 2, but scheduling conflicts led to his mutant being written out of the series in X-Men 1.

Comment: You have Evan Jonigkeit linked to the Ray Park wiki